# Оцените качество кода (чистота, рациональность написания)

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Недавно стал изучать C++ в других языках программирования ранее опыта не было. Не хочу стать "говнокодером" и т.д. Очень хочется сразу вырабатывать хороший стиль кода. Оцените пожалуйста "Калькулятор".
Может, что-то стоит убрать, что-то добавить. Сразу извинюсь, если сделал что-то "по-варварски" далеко не все еще знаю, но хочется практики поэтому пишу что-то простенькое.

```
#include "pch.h" // Необходимая библиотека (нужна для Visual Studio)
#include <iostream> // Необходимая библиотека (Основная библиотека в C++)
#include <string> // Необходимая библиотека (нужна для использования "string")

using namespace std;


float arr[1000000]; // Объвление массива переменных
int deistv[1000000]; // Объвление массива действий


int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    string action; // Введенная информация (либо число, либо действие)
    int x = 0; // Переменная для работы цикла ввода, увеличивается при введении числа
    int xt = 0; // Переменная для работы цикла ввода, увеличивается при введении действия
    int n = 0; // Переменная для работы цикла вывода (используется для создания следующего значения)
start: // Ссылка для возврата к вводу данных
    cin >> action; // Запрос данных
    if (action == "=") { // При введении "=" отправляет в функцию вывода
        goto next;
    }
    else {
        if (action == "*") { // Умножение
            deistv[xt] = 1; // Действие = "умножение"
            xt++; // Порядок действий
            goto start; // Возврат к введению данных
        }
        if (action == "/") {
            deistv[xt] = 2; // Действие = "деление"
            xt++; // Порядок действий
            goto start; // Возврат к введению данных
        }
        if (action == "+") {
            deistv[xt] = 3; // Действие = "сложение"
            xt++; // Порядок действий
            goto start; // Возврат к введению данных
        }
        if (action == "-") {
            deistv[xt] = 4; // Действие = "вычитание"
            xt++; // Порядок действий
            goto start; // Возврат к введению данных
        }
        else {
            arr[x] = stoi(action); // Присваиваем данные в массив переменных
            x++; // Порядок чисел
            goto start; // Возврат к введению данных
        }
    }
next: // Функция вывода
    for (int y = 0; y <= x; y++) { // Тут используем "x" для выделения границы цикла, цикл выполняет действия пока не закончатся ЧИСЛА
        n = y + 1; // Следующее число
        if (deistv[y] == 1) { // Умножение
            cout << arr[y] << " * " << arr[n] << " = "; // Выведение на экран "a * b = "
            arr[n] = arr[y] * arr[n]; // Число умножается на следующее за ним и результат присваивается второму множителю 
            cout << arr[n] << endl; // Окончательное заполнение формулы на экране "a * b = с"
        }
        if (deistv[y] == 2) {
            cout << arr[y] << " / " << arr[n] << " = "; // Выведение на экран "a / b = "
            arr[n] = arr[y] / arr[n]; // Число делится на следующее за ним и результат присваивается делителю 
            cout << arr[n] << endl; // Окончательное заполнение формулы на экране "a / b = с"
        }
        if (deistv[y] == 3) {
            cout << arr[y] << " + " << arr[n] << " = "; // Выведение на экран "a + b = "
            arr[n] = arr[y] + arr[n]; // Число складывается со следующим за ним и результат присваивается второму слагаемому 
            cout << arr[n] << endl; // Окончательное заполнение формулы на экране "a + b = с"
        }
        if (deistv[y] == 4) {
            cout << arr[y] << " - " << arr[n] << " = "; // Выведение на экран "a - b = "
            arr[n] = arr[y] - arr[n]; // Из числа вычитается следующее за ним и результат присваивается вычитаемому
            cout << arr[n] << endl; // Окончательное заполнение формулы на экране "a - b = с"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Вот, что выводит в консоль]

До "=" - ввод в консоль.

Comment: [tag:инспекция-кода]

Comment: Прежде всего надо проверять правильность данных, а также *есть ли вообще входные данные*.  Если в процессе ввода закрыть входной поток, то ваша программа просто зациклиться

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Код выглядит как намеренно созданный для использования на интервью клубок практик "плохого кодирования".

1. Глобальные переменные.
2. Голые массивы с размерами в стиле "этого уж точно хватит".
3. Странная манера объявлять локальные переменные в начале функции, да еще и с бессмысленными инициализаторами ("инициализаторы ради инициализаторов"). (Почему вдруг `y` правильно объявлена локально, а `n`, которая используется еще более локально, чем `y`, вдруг улетела в начало функции?)
4. Использование типа `float` вместо `double`. Кстати, если уж вы использовали плавающий тип, то почему ввод ограничен только целыми?
5. Неуместное `goto`. Причем во второй половине программы внезапно использован цикл `for`. Почему там не `goto`?
6. Магические константы (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`).
7. Абстрактные или сбивающие с толку имена переменных. (Массив данных называется просто `arr`? Удивительно, что второй массив называется `deistv`, а не `arr2`. Индексы `x` и `y`? Это координаты на плоскости что ли?)
8. Непонятные комментарии (`xt++; // Порядок действий`?)
9. Дикая манера называть заголовочные файлы "библиотеками".
10. `#include "pch.h" // Необходимая библиотека (нужна для Visual Studio)`. Нет, это не "необходимая библиотека", это  следствие непонятно зачем включенного вами режима прекомпилированных заголовков. В проекте из одного файла вам не нужны прекомпилированные заголовки.
11. `using namespace std;` - в одиноком файле реализации, наверное, можно... Но все же.
12. Множественное ветвление, реализованное через лесенку `if`, имеет смысл объединять в единое целое через `else if`, а не выписывать как последовательность независимых `if`-ов, которые делают ненужные проверки. Это не только вопрос оптимизации, но и вопрос корректности кода. У вас в первой части кода как раз содержится потенциальная ошибка, вызванная этой проблемой, от которой вас спасает только `goto start;`.

---

Переменная `x` показывает количество значений в массиве `arr`. Почему тогда цикл вычисления итерирует от `y = 0` до `y <= x`. По индексу `x` ничего нет. При этом по тому же индексу делается доступ в массив `deistv`. А кто сказал, что в массиве `deistv` вообще что-то есть?

Comment: 10. - `pch.h` это не "режим прекомпилированных заголовков", это просто некий заголовочный файл. Режим прекомпилированных заголовков включается в настройках проекта, и не факт, что он здесь включен. По списку заголовочных файлов это понять невозможно. Вас, похоже, смутило совпадение этого имени с расширением `.pch` служебных файлов VS.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду стараться исправлять недочеты. В пункте 10 "это непонятно зачем включенный вами режим прекомпилированных заголовков." без него VS выдает ошибку и отказывается включать программу.... Насчет первых пунктов, если честно до сих пор не понимаю , как объявить массив без размера в глобале. В принципе изначально программа задумывалась как множество функций, которые бы вызывались по-очереди. Но я "в порыве написания" совсем про них забыл.

Comment: @GTmix Предкомпилированные заголовки отключаются где-то в настройках проекта. На счет массивов переменной длины - лучше всего для этого использовать `std::vector` (или указатели вместе с `new[]`).

Comment: @GTmix, не заморачивайтесь с этими прекомпилированными заголовками. Даже если они у вас и в самом деле включены (что далеко не факт), для одного исходника нет никакой разницы, читаются ли стандартные заголовки в рамках прекомпиляции или сразу для компиляции. Плюс-минус миллисекунды может быть, причем в любую сторону. А если все-таки захотите выключить: правой кнопкой на проекте / "Properties..." / "C++" / "Precompiled Headers" / самый первый пункт установить в "Not Using Precompiled Headers".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , я понял, спасибо большое за помощь, буду пробовать, надеюсь получится разобраться с синтаксисом)

Comment: @freim ,спасибо за совет, взгляну на эту менюшку

Comment: @freim: Я имел в виду другое. Легенда о том, что #include для прекомпилированного заголовка включает какие-то "жизненно необходимые библиотеки", ходит среди начинающих в первую очередь потому, что удаление этого #include приводит к некомпилируемости кода. На самом же деле ничего "необходимого" там нет и этот заголовок фактически не нужен вообще. Надо только выключить прекомпиляцию заголовков в настройках проекта.

Comment: @AnT, ну вообще-то он нужен, и без него действительно полезут ошибки. Там же подключаются `windows.h`, заголовки стандартной библиотеки, и прочее прочее. Правда, обычно этот файл в Windows называется `stdafx.h`, а `pch.h` я видел только в нескольких сэмплах Platform SDK. Дело не в прекомпиляции, это просто удобно - иметь единый файл с заголовками, общими `#define` проекта, глобальными константами, и тд и тп. Идея прекомпиляции возникла уже потом - раз уж у нас есть общий заголовок для каждого исходника, давайте его скомпилируем один раз. Но по сути это вещь несвязанная.

Comment: @freim: Во-первых, этот файл в Visual Studio уже продолжительное время называется именно `pch.h`, а не `stdafx.h`. Именно поэтому `stdafx.h` больше никем не упоминается, а нынешняя волна вопросов на эту тему ссылается (и будет впредь ссылаться) именно на `pch.h`. Во-вторых, нет, манера создавать один общий файл с заголовками всегда считалась порочной практикой и популярностью не пользовалась. `stdafx.h` был придуман именно в рамках реализации механизма прекомпилированных заголовков.

Comment: @AnT, "*этот файл в Visual Studio уже продолжительное время называется именно pch.h, а не stdafx.h*" - сами-то проверяли или просто где-то услышали?. VS 2017, проекты `MFC Application`, `Windows Destop App`, `DLL App`, `Static Library` - везде по-прежнему старый добрый stdafx.h. `Pch.h` появился только в шаблоне `Console App` - не самый популярный тип приложений Windows, разве только среди студентов. "*манера создавать один общий файл с заголовками всегда считалась порочной практикой*" - вот только передергивать не надо, имелся в виду файл с **общими** заголовками, а не вообще один файл.

Comment: @freim: Если я сказал, что это так - значит это так. Так у нас здесь принято. А обязанность проверить я возлагаю на вас - в качестве задания с обязательным отчетом сюда. Именно VS2017 создает именно `pch.h`. Никакого `stdafx.h`.

Comment: @AnT, так я и проверил, прежде чем писать. VS 2017 v15.8.6 - везде `stdafx.h`, кроме шаблона `Console Application`. А задания будете жене выдавать, тоже мне, руководитель.

Answer (score 5):

В современном программировании не принято писать комментарий к каждой строчке. Обычно стараются давать говорящие имена переменным, методам, функциям и такой исходник читается как вполне осмысленный текст на английском языке.

Комментарий в коде -- вещь исключительная. Ваши же комментарии в духе "это умножение" показывают, что вы не знаете язык, на котором пишете -- но это не повод замусоривать листинг этими комментариями нужно просто знать язык программирования на котором пишете.

Далее. Вы не структурируете программу на отдельные функции. У вас одна длинная портянка кода на целых 70 строк: к концу метода уже не вспомнить, что было в начале. Процедурное  програмирование -- это в первую очередь навык декомпозиции / разбиения крупной программы на ряд более простых. Им нужно давать говорящие названия. Этого у вас никак не видно в программе.

Далее. Про goto вам сказали, но не сказали главного. Любую программу с goto можно переписать, чтобы не использовать goto. В вашем случае подойдёт бесконечый цикл while(true) с прописанным условием выхода.

Далее. Вы не пользуетесь таким оператором как switch - и пишете всё через if -- а можно было бы написать короче и понятнее.

Comment: Насчет goto сказано слишком категорично, пожалуй. Существуют ситуации, когда goto к месту. Такие ситуации редкость, но все же.

Comment: Большое спасибо , как я уже сказал "В принципе изначально программа задумывалась как множество функций, которые бы вызывались по-очереди. Но я "в порыве написания" совсем про них" Просто вижу результат, что программа работает и забываю про некоторые поправки, которые хотел сделать 5 минут назад. Учту, буду писать задание. И так стараюсь какие-то мысли перед выходом из программы записывать в комментарий в начале файла. И switch - его я полюбил изначально, просто здесь так же "в порыве" не стал уже  с if переходить на него, идея "функции вывода" была в switch. Опять забыл)

Comment: @GTmix Если у вас проблем с "забыл" -- вам очень рекомендованы такие вещи, как ревью кода с живым человеком, который будет смотреть и напоминать. Альтернатива - показывать код на stackoverflow в рубрике "инспекция кода". Например, вы можете создать новый вопрос и указав ссылку на этот показать переписанную программу, чтобы ещё раз покритиковали. Либо на самый крайний случай пишите себе "чеклист: список вопросов вида что нужно проверить после написания программы"

Comment: @A K , пока что исключительно для этого аккаунт создан, буду свои лучшие варианты скидывать на оценку, надеюсь объективно будут критиковать.

Answer (score 1):

1. Основную библиотеку нужно сначала писать так приоритет наблюдается
2. Нет комментария для `goto next`
3. Массивы малого размера - а вдруг понадобится больше?

Ну это если бегло, так можно ещё найти ИМХО

Comment: 3) Можно ли как-то объявить безразмерные( динамические ) массивы не в "main()", когда я пробовал разные варианты все ошибки выдавали, просто безразмерный массив вне функций не получился(

Answer (score -6):

У Вас вполне удобоваримый С-ишный код. Все высказанные замечания могут иметь место, но они всего лишь меняют шило на мыло или указывают на возможные ошибки. На практике я видел код гораздо хуже, но дело не в этом. Главное, что это код не С++.
Если Вы изучаете С++ тогда у Вас в программе обязано присутствовать такое слово как `class`. В этом смысле Вы всегда должны рассматривать любую задачу через призму ООП. Конкретно в данном случае Вы должны были определить объекты, их иерархию и взаимосвязь. Например, объект число, который попадает в объект выражение, который добавляется в объект калькулятор. Я не настаиваю, что архитектура должна быть именно такой, Вы можете продумать свою архитектуру. При этом можно использовать STL. В общем, я бы Вам рекомендовал рассмотреть данную задачу в таком контексте и переписать используя всю мощь С++, STL и ООП.

("Совершенный код" Стив Макконнелл):

> В объектно-ориентированном программировании методы, не умещающиеся на экране монитора, требуются редко и обычно свидетельствуют о попытке насильно втиснуть ногу структурного программирования в объектно-ориентированный ботинок.

Оттуда же:

> Типичная история такова: «Мы писали новую систему на C++, но большинство наших программистов не имели особого опыта работы на C++. Раньше они использовали Fortran. Они писали код, который компилировался на C++, но на самом деле это был замаскированный Fortran. В итоге они заставили C++ эмулировать недостатки языка Fortran (такие как операторы goto и глобальные данные) и проигнорировали богатый набор объектно-ориентированных возможностей C++». Данный феномен наблюдается
> в отрасли уже много лет (Hanson, 1984; Yourdon, 1986a).

Это же можно сказать о тех кто раньше писал или изучал С.

Также полезно придерживаться подобных правил [MISRA](https://analyst.phyzdev.net/documentation/help/concepts/candccheckerreference.htm)
и которые в частности, например, запрещают использование [atoi](https://analyst.phyzdev.net/documentation/help/reference/misra.stdlib.atoi.htm)

Дополнительно:

Нахождение чисел Фибоначчи в момент компиляции для С++:
[Поиск в google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Y9zpX4ziLLOWjgaY3auIDg&q=fibonacci+C%2B%2B+metaprogramming&oq=fibonaccci+C%2B%2B+metaprogramming&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQFhAeOgYIABAIEB5QAFgAYMRQaABwAHgAgAFTiAGcAZIBATKYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjMn4P54vDtAhUzi8MKHZjuCuEQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)

Comment: *"направить в нужное русло"* - *"Если Вы изучаете С++ тогда у Вас в программе обязано присутствовать такое слово как class"* Ну не знаю.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat " Ну не знаю" - вот  именно.

Comment: *"вот именно"* Не понял. Я имею в виду, что ООП - это инструмент. Иногда он нужен, иногда - нет. Что же, и hello world обязательно с классами писать?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Именно напрямую связанный с С++, который человек изучает. И, в этом смысле даже Hello world не просто можно, а нужно  вывести через класс.

Comment: Большое спасибо за отзыв, постараюсь учесть все, пока только начал читать литературу по языку поэтому с ООП все плохо, даже не задумывался об использовании структурирования в калькуляторе)

Comment: Что за бред, алгоритм нахождения чисел Фибоначчи вы тоже будете оборачивать в классы?

Comment: Поинтересуйтесь например метапрограммированием https://medium.com/@milot/fibonacci-sequence-and-c-template-meta-programming-adfa760522ed